# Any idea how to check if a div contains ONLY an image tag inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to search this on stackoverflow but the answers arent exactly what im looking for, plus they use jquery. So is there any way of determing if a div element contains only an image element inside it, and therefore returning a boolean?
I have tried things like:

```
<div className={this.find('img').length}?'hasImg':'noImg'>
 <img src=''>
  </div>
```

but this returned false. Even if this would work, I'd like it to return true only if there is an image regardless if there is a p tag or something else inside.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: seems like it would make sense to do this in React, but we see not code.

Comment: i didnt put code as i dont not know how to approach this

Comment: That makes no sense.... What in the react is actually setting the image/content?

Comment: what do you mean image/content? the source?

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? Maybe there's some other way to approach this.

Comment: i want to do this because im building a chat app, and so i want to apply different styles if there is only an image present in that div.

Comment: But aren't you setting the content of that div yourself? Say the images are present in the `images` state (array). You could then use `images.length`. Providing more context might lead to a better solution here.

Comment: I'm retrieving HTML string from firebase, firestore, which is then converted to HTML elements with dangerouslysethtml property inside a div. therefore i want to determine if the innerhtml of the div contains only an image tag, and if it does i want to style that parent div differently.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to this world, but messing around a little I created this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300" alt="">
</div>
```

JS

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

const booleanResult = checkChildElement()

function checkChildElement(){
if(container.childElementCount === 1 && container.children[0].tagName === 'IMG'){
   return true
}
else{
   return false
}
}

console.log(booleanResult)
```

Comment: how would you do it if there were more than one container, so for example, change the class of the parent div to container and hasImg, and the container that doesnt contain an image, return container.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isImageExist: false,
    totalImages: 0,
    isRender: false,
  };
  checkIsImage(ref) {
    if (ref && !this.state.isRender) {
      let totalImages = Object.entries(ref.children).filter(
        ([key, child]) => child.nodeName === "IMG"
      );
      this.setState({
        totalImages: totalImages.length,
        isImageExist: totalImages.length > 0,
        isRender: true,
      });
      console.log("Total Images", totalImages.length);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.checkIsImage(ref);
        }}
      >
        <img
          src={`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4185aac47f6262b40dc8f11535a32c0?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG`}
        ></img>
        <img
          src={`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4185aac47f6262b40dc8f11535a32c0?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG`}
        ></img>
        <p>{this.state.totalImages}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you writing in class based components? that is so 2018. provide functional components like everyone else its 2021

Comment: @Aviale Right! ,  most of the projects are based on class based components so it's easy for the reader, and of course, FC has lots of advantage over class based, I am one of the hooks lovers <3

Comment: I'd use this if i were familiar with old react, D:. But maybe it will help someone else so thanks!